# SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition slow performance

Tags: sql-server

We use SQL Server 2008 R2 in our production environment and we are looking into upgrading to SQL Server 2019.

So I just installed SQL Server 2019 Developer Edition on my computer to test it out, grab a fresh backup from the production server and made a restore on my computer.

I also have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed on my computer so I was looking forward to some side by side performance comparisons.

Both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2019 are installed on the same nvme drive (C:), and also both instances are on that same drive, however, SQL Server 2019 tempdb is on another drive (D:)

Running a particular stored procedure took **1:43s** on SQL Server 2008 R2, and **3:41** on SQL Server 2019 ... I ran that stored procedure  about a dozen times with about the same results (add / subtract a couple of seconds)

During the stored procedure execution, disk IO barely reaches 6MB/s for read and write and CPU utilization is at about 10% both for SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2019

I restarted my computer and run the stored procedure again on the 2019 instance first, same results (I was afraid that somehow SQL Server 2008 R2 had grabbed all the available memory which wasn't the case)

So I tried all this, running the stored procedure again in between to check if any improvement was made:

- Restarted

  - Deleted both the SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2019 databases and made the restore again (just to make absolutely sure that the dataset is identical)
  - I turned off Windows Defender
  - I made sure that the same system account `LocalSystem` were being used by both SQL Server 2008 R2 and SQL Server 2019 to start the engine
  - In SQL Server 2019 I changed the DB `compat level` from 2008 (10) to 2019 (15)
  - In SQL Server 2019 rebuild the main indexes (afraid the 2019 won't be able to take full advantage of an index created with 2008 R2)
  - Moved SQL Server 2019 tempdb to the same drive (C:) as the DB (same as it is set on SQL Server 2008 R2)

The only difference I can see is that my SQL Server 2008 R2 is a `default instance` while SQL Server 2019 is a `named instance`, but I can't even think off why that will affect performance so drastically.

Does the **Developer Edition** have some kind of performance penalty???

What I'm missing?

Comment: For starters, you're missing almost 11 years of development on the optimizer. SQL Server 2019's optimizer and engine work quite differently, even with the compat level turned down. Note that "different" does not necessarily mean "faster in every case". Don't bother with the hardware first, compare execution plans! (2019 at least does give you Query Store, which makes gathering and comparing execution plans much nicer.)

Comment: IIRC Developer Edition is effectively the same as Enterprise, just not licensed for production use. So it is the right one to use, yes.

Comment: @Jeroen thanks for the suggestion... I wasn't able to stop any differences except in some minor 'cost %'... I also got 2 'missing index' messages but they also appear in the SQL2008R2 execution plan too. I will explore this further

Comment: Have you updated statistics? I'd go with rebuilding all indexes (which you did) and updating all statistics any time when restoring on a new system. Another thing: a better place to ask questions like yours is https://dba.stackexchange.com (if you do ask the same question, delete the one here though, cross-posting is frowned upon on Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft claims that the Development version of SQL server is the same of the Enterprise version of it,
But when you try to test it using a real test you will find limitations, (consider using HammerDb for testing)
[Here](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/performance-differences-between-developer-and-enterprise-editions#post-1939285) is someone is facing the same issue, it says in summary:

> Enterprise is lightning, Dev is dog slow.

The question is: why Microsoft does not provide a clear limitations for development license? I **think** because it was made to be used in development only and there is no point to use all processors and memory on the server in the development, and it is illegal to use it in production, so there is no point to provide such information